# Line graph only appears a half in the gut

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I try to make a line graph with python and the graph only appears a half of the canvas and the rest is only black in the GUI. The data that should be appear was taken from the database.

[image]

```
###----------------Connecting to the database-------------##### 
import sqlite3 
DB = sqlite3.connect ("personal_project.db")

CURSOR = DB.cursor()
###----------------create the SQL command to create the table and save data-------------######
 COMMAND1 = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
          balance (
          UserID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
          Date TEXT,
          Amount TEXT,
          Descriotion)"""
 CURSOR.execute(COMMAND1)

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

###----------------Create the window-------------#####
main_WINDOW = Tk()
main_WINDOW.title("Study App")
main_WINDOW.geometry("1940x1080")#width*length
main_WINDOW.configure(bg="#ffffff")   


###------Show Information Using Graph-------###
graquery = '''SELECT Date, Amount FROM balance'''
CURSOR.execute(graquery)
graresults = CURSOR.fetchall()
Date = [result[0] for result in graresults]
Amount = [result[1] for result in graresults]
figure = plt.figure()
plt.plot(Date, Amount)
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Amount')
plt.title('Balance graph Graph')
gracanvas = Canvas(main_WINDOW, width=1070, height=452)
gracanvas.place(x=356, y=270)
figure_canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, gracanvas)
gracanvas.create_window(0,0,window=figure_canvas.get_tk_widget(), anchor="nw") 


main_WINDOW.mainloop()
```

Comment: Maybe you need to convert your dates to proper matplotlib or pandas date format?

Comment: Can you make a [*minimal* example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? The code can neither be executed by anyone but you, nor should there be SQL code in a question about a plot (use dummy data if you must),

Comment: You can adjust the graph size by specifying `figsize` option in `figure = plt.figure(figsize=(width,height))`.  However I would recommend you to look at the official document on ["Embedded in Tk"](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk_sgskip.html).